# diffrence between return a resolved promise and regular promise which only handles resolve

Tags: javascript

what is the difference between the followings: 
In my opinion they both return a resolved promise but I think it might not be correct. I was wondering if they is a difference ?

```
getQuery =  function () {
   return Promise.resolve({
        name: "some query name";
   });
}

executeQuery = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           resolve(mockQueryResult);
    }); },
```

Comment: I agree with you. I recall reading that there are two ways to do the same thing with promises. I think you just described those two ways and that one thing.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [ECMAScript 2015 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.resolve) (emphasis mine):

> The resolve function returns either a **new promise resolved with the passed argument**, or the argument itself if the argument is a promise produced by this constructor.

Then reading further down in the implementation:

> `6. Let resolveResult be Call(promiseCapability.[[Resolve]], undefined, «x»).`

I believe this means that according to the spec, the results of the two are identical. Of course, if you're using a third-party library or polyfill, it's possible that you might get different results.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the first function recall the resolve method of the class Promise. The second function returns and instantiates a promise object, and this function becomes an async func and if it goes well then recall the resolve.

```
 getQuery =  function () {
   Promise.resolve({
    name: "some query name";
   });
 }

executeQuery = function () {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     resolve(mockQueryResult);
}); },
```